# dict get with condition in Python

Tags: python

```
foo = {}
print 'yes' if foo.get('bar', None) else None
```

Is there any way if I can improve this code?

Logic: if bar key is there, print 'yes' else print None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize what you want and create a simple function which returns `yes` if the `key` is present in your dict, otherwise returns `None`:

```
def key_exists(foo, key):
    """
    foo -> dictionary
    key -> lookup key
    Return foo if key exists in foo. Otherwise, return None
    """
    return 'yes' if key in foo else None

print(key_exists({'a': 'b'}, 'a'))
print(key_exists({'a': 'b'}, 'c'))
print(key_exists({}, 'c'))
```

The output for the above:

```
yes
None
None
```

If you, however, don't need a special message if the `key` is being found in the dict, and want to return a default value if it isn't found, you can do:

```
def key_exists(foo, key):
    """
    foo -> dictionary
    key -> lookup key
    Return foo if key exists in foo. Otherwise, return None
    """
    return foo.get(key, None)
```

The output for the above:

```
b
None
None
```

*PS: Note that above (as Graipher mentioned) it's enough to directly return `foo.get(key)` as `None` is the default value anyway.*

You usually want to use `dict.get(key[, default])` when you need to assign default values. When `get()` is called, Python checks if the specified key exists in the dict. If it does, then `get()` returns the value of that key (which is not exactly what you want). If the key does not exist, then `get()` returns the value specified in the second argument to `get()`. That being said, you should go with the first solution

Apart from that, you should also know that doing `'key' in dict` is faster than any other method. The time to find a key using this method is \$O(1)\$ whereas calling keys would generate a list and be \$O(n)\$

Comment: so just I can just do: `print  'yes' if 'bar' in foo else None`

Comment: Indeed, you can do it like this

Comment: You can also just do `return foo.get(key)`. `get` returns `None` by default if the key is not found.

Comment: I personally don't think bespoke functions are the correct solution, the contents of your functions I agree with. Take `key_exists(foo, bar)`, which is more cryptic and longer than `foo.get(bar)`.

Comment: Yup, that one looks cryptic but it was just an example to show OP how things work. It also doesn't apply to his use case (which is why I recommended the first solution) ;P I'll mention it anywayz for the sake of completness.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you use `get` because you want to look at the value, then you should change it to `foo.get('bar', False)`, or you can just be implicit and change it to `foo.get('bar')`
2. if however you just want to check if the value exist - be explicit about it and use `'bar' in foo` instead of `get`.
3. do you actually want to print `None`? if not - then you should change the code to `if ...: print 'yes'`
4. there are other ways to write this code, but I think that this way is the most readable. Maybe it's a matter of taste. Here are other options that people might like:

`print (None, 'yes')['bar' in foo]`

`print foo.get('bar', None) or 'yes'` (note that this will change the logic a bit: for example when `foo['bar'] == False` it will print `False`.

Comment: I have updated the Question with Logic. and this one `print ('yes', None')['bar' in foo]` doesn't work.

Comment: @VaibhavMule Try `print (None, 'yes')['bar' in foo]` or `print((None, 'yes')['bar' in foo])` if you're using python 3.x.

Comment: Right, my mistake. I'll edit the answer with the reverse tuple.